# How to retrieve from Firebase into an array using Swift 3?

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have this firebase structure

[image]

```
{
  "English" : {
    "-Kf1-6xbGqxAgWEWkPMO" : {
      "CorrectAnswer" : "asdf",
      "OptionA" : "a1",
      "OptionB" : "b1",
      "OptionC" : "c1",
      "Question" : "Question1"
    },
    "-Kf9ap_0ja3rwEGPn-lz" : {
      "CorrectAnswer" : "fdas",
      "OptionA" : "a2",
      "OptionB" : "b2",
      "OptionC" : "C2",
      "Question" : "Question2"
    }
    ...//more questions
  },
   "AnotherSubject" : {
    "-Kf1-6xbGqxAgWEWkPMO" : {
      "CorrectAnswer" : "asdf",
      "OptionA" : "a1",
      "OptionB" : "b1",
      "OptionC" : "c1",
      "Question" : "Question1"
    },
    "-Kf9ap_0ja3rwEGPn-lz" : {
      "CorrectAnswer" : "fdas",
      "OptionA" : "a2",
      "OptionB" : "b2",
      "OptionC" : "C2",
      "Question" : "Question2"
    }
    ...//more questions
  },
  "Users" : {
    "E2Ym1qb0dIT8zARlLLxEOCheg4E3" : {
      "email" : "adsf@gmail.com",
      "name" : "asdf asdf"
    },
    "vL8p17oDFaUp0iJCQYNS0xgntyg2" : {
      "email" : "sdf@gmail.com",
      "name" : "sadfsd"
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

How can i retrieve this "Question" and and save into an array like

```
var question = ["Question1", "Question2",...],
```

and these "Answer", "optionA", "optionB" into a var of

```
var answer = [["Answer","a1","b1","c1"], ["Answer2","a2","b2","c2"],[...]]
```

Any help is much appreciated. I know there's a hundred ways to do it. An efficient way to get the same result is a huge help.

Comment: let child = snapshot.children //Get all question key array here

Comment: a little code would help. I am really new in firebase. And i can't find firebase retrieve using swift 3. If you have can you send me a link pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create question model to get questions and contents of the questions in to an array. Cast your snapshot to `Dictionary` then get the values;

```
    class QuestionModel: NSObject {
         var CorrectAnswer: String!
         var Question: String!
         var optionA: String!
         var optionB: String!
         var optionC: String!

         init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
            if let snapshotDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                CorrectAnswer = snapshotDict["CorrectAnswer"] as? String
                Question = snapshotDict["Question"] as? String
                optionA = snapshotDict["optionA"] as? String
                optionB = snapshotDict["optionB"] as? String
                optionC = snapshotDict["optionC"] as? String      
            }
        }
       }
```

in your callback;

```
var questionModels : [QuestionModel] = []
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("English").observe(.value, with: {
            snapshot in

            for child in snapshot.children {
                let user = QuestionModel.init(snapshot: (child as? FIRDataSnapshot)!)
                self.questionModels.append(user)
            }


        })
```

You must send requests as many as nodes count like `FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("English")`, `FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("AnotherSubject")`. And you don't need to `var answer = [["Answer","a1","b1","c1"], ["Answer2","a2","b2","c2"],[...]]`. The question array you have will do the same thing. You can do `questionModels[0].CorrectAnswer` or whatever you want

Comment: Added my JSON. Please take a look again please.

Comment: Accepted your answer. Thanks bro it really help me :) Anyway, if  i have outlet button named myLabel and i want "Question" from firebase to display on it. I tried let Question = snapshotDict["Question"] as? String by myLabel.text = Question but it doesn't. You have idea how can display it bro?

Comment: Is there an exception or just display empty string? If it is empty, try to check it in debug mode.  snapshotDict["Question"] can be empty when it returns from firebase @JohnDoe

Comment: With exemption. Could you help me and just put a print statement in your code so that i can understand it well. Thanks again i really appreciate it :)

Comment: Thanks bro, i solved it. I put outside snapshot using this self.qLabel.text = self.questionModel[0].Question. It did display my question to the label. heheh now my problem is getting those answer and options into a button. I found making an array of buttons... Ty again for the time hehehe.

Comment: How can i move from questionModels[0].CorrectAnswer to questionModel[1].CorrectAnswer?